# I want to move the value in the tuple to the list

Tags: python, list, algorithm, tuples

```
rows = [(747652126187978752, 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', '2020-11-03 18:46:57')]
alr_exist2 = []
ex = 0
for row in rows :
            ex = row
            alr_exist2.append(ex[0])
            ex = 0
print(alr_exist2)
```

If I run the code above, I want the following output:

```
[747652126187978752, 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', '2020-11-03 18:46:57']
```

How can I fix the error?

Comment: Did you mean: `alr_exist2 = list(rows[0])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
rows = [(747652126187978752, 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', '2020-11-03 18:46:57')]

alr_exist2 = [item for sublist in [row for row in rows] for item in sublist]

print(alr_exist2)
```

Output:

```
[747652126187978752, 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', '2020-11-03 18:46:57']
```

Comment: You dont really need to transform the tuple to a list to make this work

Comment: Besides, creating two loop is memory exhaustion in terms of performance. By default, 1 loop is equal `24 bytes` which is HUGE compare to loop

Comment: Ok...Then I will merge both into one single loop.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to flatten it:

```
alr_exist2 = [item for sublist in rows for item in sublist]
```

Output:

```
[747652126187978752, 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', '2020-11-03 18:46:57']
```

Answer (score 1):

> *I think, you have to **unpack** the list of tuples, first. Then insert the data into a freshed list.*

```py
rows = [(747652126187978752, 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', '2020-11-03 18:46:57')]

newList = []

for row in rows[0]: 
    """Here I specified the first tuple in the List because 
       there's only one tuple in the list. If there're more than 
       one, you have to make `nasted loop` >> 2d looping."""

    newList.append(row)

Print(newList)
```

***OUTPUT***

```
[747652126187978752, 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', '2020-11-03 18:46:57']
```

Answer (score 1):

[`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) would be a nice pythonic solution as well

```py
rows = [(747652126187978752, 'NULL', 'NULL'), ('NULL', '2020-11-03 18:46:57')]
res = list(itertools.chain(*rows))
```

#### Output

```py
>>> rows = [(747652126187978752, 'NULL', 'NULL'), ('NULL', '2020-11-03 18:46:57')]
>>> list(itertools.chain(*rows))
[747652126187978752, 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', '2020-11-03 18:46:57']
>>> rows = [(747652126187978752, 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', '2020-11-03 18:46:57')]
>>> list(itertools.chain(*rows))
[747652126187978752, 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', '2020-11-03 18:46:57']
```

Comment: Why have you used a different definition of `rows` to the OP?

Comment: @quamrana mostly because OP's one was only a singular element tuple, but sure I'll add both